# List View not wrapping

Tags: android, listview

i have linear layout like this :

```
<LinearLayout
                android:id="@+id/quizViewTwo"
                android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:orientation="vertical">
                <LinearLayout
                    android:id="@+id/answer_layoutTwo"
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
                    android:orientation="vertical"/>
            </LinearLayout>
```

Now i am progrmatically adding the List View to `answer_layoutTwo` the due to some constraints,

```
ListView ansList = new ListView(Test.this);
ansList.setAdapter(adapter);
ansCellLayout.addView(ansList);// here ansCellLayout is answer_layoutTwo
```

now the list view is not wrapping its only displaying the first item and their its having a scroll view.

i have tried adding layout params to also tried adding weight and its not working.

**EDIT**

i tried adding `ansList.setLayoutParams(new LinearLayout.LayoutParams(LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT, 600));`

and it works fine but if i give FillParent it will not work :(

Comment: show your activity ansCellLayout.addView(ansList); code

Answer (score 0):

your first `LinearLayout` specifies `android:layout_height="wrap_content"` that may be the reason. Also why do you nest two vertical linear layouts?

Comment: in the first linera lyout i am adding some view and in second linear layout adding some other view so 2 different layouts

Comment: did u use scrollview in your layout?

Comment: @Arash yes i am using scroll view above the first linear layout

Comment: @Goofy : Don't use listview inside of a ScrollView.ListViews contains ScrollView Itself.

Comment: @Arash no even if i remove that its the same problem

Comment: If you provide your compelete java listview codes and layout maybe we can help you more.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/22306/discussion-between-goofy-and-arash)